# Filtering Laravel Eloquent call by something in the with clause

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building an app based off of the Laravel bootcamp app and I'm trying to add additional filtering based off of the with statement.

Some probably obvious things:

1. each user has a city
2. each call has a user referenced by user_id

```
public function index()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $city = $user->city;
        return Inertia::render('Calls/Index', [
            'calls' => Call::with('user:id,name,city,state,email')->latest()->get(),
           
        
        ]);
    }
```

I need to only get calls whose user has the same location as them. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving model records, you may wish to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship, there is where you can use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

I presume you have a relation in your Interia Model refer to User model:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

now you can make you code like this:

```
return Inertia::render('Calls/Index', [
  'calls' => Call::with('user:id,name,city,state,email')->whereHas('user',function ($q) use ($city) {
        $q->where('city',$city);
    })->latest()->get(),


]);
```